Web3.py gas_price does not exactly match value from transaction
I'm using the web3 python provider to get the value of the gas_price property, but when I compare it with the value from an Etherscan transaction it is slightly off. Could this be just due to timing?
i.e.:
Etherscan value: 14.750473539 Gwei; 
gas_price value: 14352529506 (in WEI)

The slight difference in the gas price values is likely due to timing differences when the data was fetched. Additionally, libraries like web3.py, web3.js, ethers.js, etc. provide the estimated gas price value, not the actual gas price. Therefore, the actual gas price at the time of transaction execution could be slightly different from the estimated one. This difference usually increases during periods of network congestion or high network usage.
